# Convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS to utc

Tags: datetime, elixir, utc

I have a string input having the following format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS
2022-04-14 15:30:00
```

How can I convert this string to utc format in elixir. Ideally I should look something like this

```
2022-04-14T15:30:00Z
```

In elixir

I have tried

```
DateTime.from_iso8601!("2022-04-14 15:30:00") |> DateTime.to_utc
```

But keep getting

> function DateTime.from_iso8601!/1 is undefined or private.

Comment: Probably you should do a bit more research.  As the answer points out, there is no from_iso8601! function--which is exactly what the error message is saying.

Comment: There is no such thing as "UTC format". UTC is a time zone. You apparently meant "ISO 8601 format" (a very complicated format with a lot of variants, I suggest to limit yourself to the profile of RFC 3339, as in your example).

Answer (score 3):

Beware of typos! The function name is `from_iso8601` NOT 86011. It does not include the `!`. See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_iso8601/2
Secondly, your input string is NOT a valid 8601 formatted string because it omits the offset.  So even if you specify the proper function name, it will still error out:

```
iex> DateTime.from_iso8601("2022-04-14 15:30:00")
{:error, :missing_offset}
```

If you need to parse a string like this, you can use a library like `timex`, or you can manually parse the string, e.g. using regex or manually deconstructing the string and then calling `DateTime.new/4`

Adam's example is more elegant and far simpler if you know the format lines up with what 8601 requires, but here's an long-winded "academic" example of manually deconstructing a string using the `<<>>` syntax:

```
# Deconstruct the string
iex> <<year::binary-size(4), "-", month::binary-size(2), "-", day::binary-size(2), " ", hour::binary-size(2), ":", minute::binary-size(2), ":", second::binary-size(2)>> = "2022-04-14 15:30:00"

# Convert strings to integers
iex> year = String.to_integer(year)
iex> month = String.to_integer(month)
iex> day = String.to_integer(day)
iex> hour = String.to_integer(hour)
iex> minute = String.to_integer(minute)
iex> second = String.to_integer(second)

# Assemble the parts
iex> {:ok, date} = Date.new(year, month, day)
iex> {:ok, time} = Time.new(hour, minute, second)

# Combine
iex> {:ok, datetime} = DateTime.new(date, time, "Etc/UTC")

iex> DateTime.to_iso8601(datetime)
"2022-04-14T15:30:00Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to format the string, and don't care about the [`DateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html) type at all, you can do:

```elixir
iex> String.replace("2022-04-14 15:30:00", " ", "T") <> "Z"
"2022-04-14T15:30:00Z"
```

If you want a `DateTime`:

```elixir
iex> {:ok, datetime, 0} = DateTime.from_iso8601("2022-04-14 15:30:00" <> "Z")
{:ok, ~U[2022-04-14 15:30:00Z], 0}
iex> datetime
~U[2022-04-14 15:30:00Z]
```

You could also pipe into [`elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2) (but the previous example is better because you will get a match error if you convert to a non-UTC offset):

```elixir
iex> DateTime.from_iso8601("2022-04-14 15:30:00" <> "Z") |> elem(1)
~U[2022-04-14 15:30:00Z]
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution,
Used the changeset to cast it to utc format

```
{%{}, %{some_date: :utc_datetime }} 
|> Ecto.Changeset.cast(%{some_date:parsed_date}, 
[:some_date, :end_date])
```

Comment: Naive date time does not contain a timezone at all, but you asked for an ISO date time in UTC such as `2022-04-14T15:30:00Z`.

Comment: This is not a solution to a problem stated by any means. Downvoted.

Comment: Your downvote is appreciated. I have a lot to learn. Thanks for your time